# Operations in multi index dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to process geographic and statistical data from a big data csv. It contains data from geographical administrative and geostatistical. Municipality, Location, geostatistical basic division and block constitute the hierarchical indexes.

I have to create a new column ['data2'] for every element the max value of the data in the geo index, and divide each block value by that value. For each index level, and the index level value must be different from 0, because the 0 index level value accounts for other types of info not used in the calculation.

```
                       data1  data2
mun  loc  geo  block
1    0    0    0       20     20
1    1    0    0       10     10
1    1    1    0       10     10   
1    1    1    1       3      3/4
1    1    1    2       4      4/4
1    1    2    0       30     30   
1    1    2    1       1      1/3
1    1    2    2       3      3/3
1    2    1    1       10     10/12
1    2    1    2       12     12/12
2    1    1    1       123    123/123
2    1    1    2       7      7/123
2    1    2    1       6      6/6
2    1    2    2       1      1/6
```

Any ideas? I have tried with for loops, converting the indexes in columns with reset_index() and iterating by column and row values but the computation is taking forever and I think that is not the correct way to do this kind of operations.

Also, what if I want to get my masks like this, so I can run my calculations to every level.

```
mun  loc  geo  block
1    0    0    0     False       
1    1    0    0     False       
1    1    1    0     True          
1    1    1    1     False        
1    1    1    2     False        
1    1    2    0     True          
1    1    2    1     False        
1    1    2    2     False        

mun  loc  geo  block
1    0    0    0     False       
1    1    0    0     True       
1    1    1    0     False          
1    1    1    1     False        
1    1    1    2     False
1    2    0    0     True
1    2    2    0     False          
1    2    2    1     False        

mun  loc  geo  block
1    0    0    0     True       
1    1    0    0     False       
1    1    1    0     False          
1    1    1    1     False        
1    1    1    2     False
2    0    0    0     True
2    1    1    0     False          
2    1    2    1     False
```

Comment: So you need remove first 4 rows of Dataframe, because in hierarchical indexes are `0` ? And in first row of `df2` it is (0 / max(0,0,7.15,9.85)) ? And in second (`0` / ???) ? Can you add numbers for second and third row in output? Thanks. I think it is a bit unclear.

Comment: Edited for clarity. I don't need to remove those rows, I just don't need to run the operations on them, also, 0 not only appears at the top, but at the end of each index value too, so you have all the blocks of geo, and all geos of loc, and all loc of municipality. with the 0 indexes referring to the totals by index. I need to run the max operator to all the blocks of each geo of each loc of each mun and then divide the data1 value for that block by the max, respecting the hierarchical order.

Comment: Thank you for edit . But I think better instaed `value`, `value`.. give sample data e.g. `1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5` and then formulas with numbers are (1 / 4) for first row, then (2 / 2) ? Can you extend sample with numbers and some rows (if necessary) for clarity? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the help. More editing has been done. Put some examples of indexes with value 0. Also, the dataframe contains 80 000 + rows of hierarchical combination. Each index has more element but i just put a few for example purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create `mask` from [`MultiIndex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html), compare with `0` and check at least one `True` (at least one `0`) by [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
mask = (pd.DataFrame(df.index.values.tolist(), index=df.index) == 0).any(axis=1)
print (mask)
mun  loc  geo  block
1    0    0    0         True
     1    0    0         True
          1    0         True
               1        False
               2        False
          2    0         True
               1        False
               2        False
     2    1    1        False
               2        False
2    1    1    1        False
               2        False
          2    1        False
               2        False
dtype: bool
```

Then get [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html) values by [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) per first, second and third index, but before filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) only values where are not `True` in `mask`:

```
df1 = df.ix[~mask, 'data1'].groupby(level=['mun','loc','geo']).max()
print (df1)
mun  loc  geo
1    1    1        4
          2        3
     2    1       12
2    1    1      123
          2        6
```

Then [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) `df1` by `df.index`, remove last level of `Multiindex` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) values where no change by `mask` (also is necessary remove last level) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) by `1`, because dividing return same value.

```
df1 = df1.reindex(df.reset_index(level=3, drop=True).index)
         .mask(mask.reset_index(level=3, drop=True)).fillna(1)
print (df1)
Name: data1, dtype: int64
mun  loc  geo
1    0    0        1.0
     1    0        1.0
          1        1.0
          1        4.0
          1        4.0
          2        1.0
          2        3.0
          2        3.0
     2    1       12.0
          1       12.0
2    1    1      123.0
          1      123.0
          2        6.0
          2        6.0
Name: data1, dtype: float64
```

Last divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
print (df['data1'].div(df1.values,axis=0))
mun  loc  geo  block
1    0    0    0        20.000000
     1    0    0        10.000000
          1    0        10.000000
               1         0.750000
               2         1.000000
          2    0        30.000000
               1         0.333333
               2         1.000000
     2    1    1         0.833333
               2         1.000000
2    1    1    1         1.000000
               2         0.056911
          2    1         1.000000
               2         0.166667
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Working with MultiIndex is not easy, I hope it works very well.

Comment: Very useful thank you very much. I just need one more answer. What if I want to create a mask that goes:

    mun  loc  geo  block
    1    0    0    0         True1    0    0         True
          1    0         True
               1        False
               2        False

Comment: I screwed the comment sorry. What if I want a mask that goes:
mun  loc  geo  block
1    0    0    0         True
     1    0    0         True
          1    0         True
               1        False
               2        False
          2    0         True
               1        False
               2        False

Comment: I am not sure if i understand you. You need mask what have same size as Dataframe and have same index if need [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).  Can you explain more?

Comment: Can't seem to be able to edit the comments. Anyways, now I need to make a mask that goes like this [1 1 1 0] = true / [1 1 0 0] = false / [1 1 1 1 ] = false and so on, then another mask [1 1 0 0 ] = true / [1 1 0 1 ]. So now I can group and get the max of all geo within loc and divide just like before.

Comment: @marco - Can you edit question? Formating in comment is problematic ;)

Comment: I did more editing to clarify my work. Create more masks depending of the index level. I need to do this because 0 valued indexes account for the total of that area: [ 1 1 1 1] means one block, [1 1 1 0] means total of blocks by geo, [1 1 0 0] means totals by loc etc. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @marco - Thanks for edit. I think if you have first, second or third mask, my solution works very well. But there is another thing - you need some logic for creating mask. So if you need help with creating some mask, I think the best is create another question.

Comment: Is it problem for you? Because in StackOverflow the best approach is separated each problem to question. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125660/discussion-between-marco-and-jezrael).